# Undefined error for audio in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have an array of image .png files and a matching array of .mp3s. Clicking on the image should play the audio by passing the index from one array to the other, however I am getting the "undefined" error for the last line.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var starting_pics = ["CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];
    var starting_sounds = ["CN.mp3", "EN.mp3", "GN.mp3"];

    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {
        $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + starting_pics[i]).load(function () {
            $(this).appendTo("#main");
            $(this).addClass("pics");
        });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < starting_sounds.length; i++) {
        $("<audio/>").attr("src", "audio/" + starting_sounds[i]).load(function () {
            $(this).appendTo("#main");
            $(this).addClass("sound");
        });
    }

    $("#main").on("click", ".pics", function () {
        var i = $(this).index();
        alert(i);
        $(".sound").get(i).play();
    });
});
```

Comment: which last line? you gotta be more clear

Comment: ha ha I read your comment and your username quickly and I thought "wow that's pretty harsh" :)

Comment: $(".sound").get(i).play();

Comment: Try the code here http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/DFgFx/

Comment: Some modifications to that fiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kaB6V/) - it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Omar. This works. why?

Comment: The items were not appending properly, you didn't need need `.load()` with a callback.

Comment: @Pointy thanks the updated fiddle. I'm using iPad; Its hard to provide a 100% working fiddle =)

Comment: I will add an answer.

Comment: Two things: that version of `load` is deprecated since jQuery 1.8 - use `$("selector").on("load, func...`. And make sure you bind the `load` event **before** you set the `src` attribute - some browsers will fire the `load` event immediately when the `src` is set, if it's been cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are not properly appended by using `.load()`, do the following modifications.

```
for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {
  $("<img/>").attr("src", "" + starting_pics[i])
             .appendTo("#main")
             .addClass("pics");
}

for (i = 0; i < starting_sounds.length; i++) {
  $("<audio/>").attr("src", "" + starting_sounds[i])
               .appendTo("#main")
               .addClass("sound");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

That version of `.load()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.8 - use `$("selector").on("load, func...`. And make sure you bind the `load` event before you set the `src` attribute - some browsers will fire the `load` event immediately when the `src is set, if it's been cached.

In addition, `<audio>` elements don't seem to have a `load` event. That's why the elements weren't being found - the `load` event never executed, so they weren't appended. The events you want to look into are `canplay` or `canplaythrough`, or something from this list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Media_events

Comment: The point of the `load` was to make sure the images were **loaded** before appending them to the DOM. I don't see how this fixes anything

Comment: @lan if you see this answer is incorrect, pls add another comprehensive answer and I'll be more than happy to remove this.

Comment: I don't see it as incorrect, it's just that it doesn't *fix* the problem...it circumvents it by ignoring it. It really depends on what the OP wants/wanted...and the loading happens fast enough that you probably shouldn't run into a problem with your code. Nonetheless, if the OP wants the elements to be added only after they're loaded, the `load` event needs to be listened to for images, and the `canplaythrough` event for audio elements (both `after` setting the `src`).

Comment: It also might've made sense to use `.trigger("play")` instead of `.get(i).play()` so it safely tries to trigger the event. If the audio element isn't added to the DOM, `.get(i).play()` will throw the error the OP is seeing

Comment: @lan pls go ahead and add what you've said as an answer. It looks way better than mine and I guess this is what the OP wants. Not to mention that this could prevent any problem that might occur.

Comment: @lan I am still waiting :)

Comment: (i) clicked is in the starting_pics array, (i).play() is in the starting_sounds array. How would .trigger("play") get the correct file??

Comment: @jwelter It wouldn't get the correct file; it would just silently/safely fail, like some other jQuery methods. Using `.get(i)`, you get the DOM element. When using jQuery methods, you're manipulating the jQuery object